# Find the "minimum" custom category in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, function

Working with pandas DataFrames, I'm looking to be able to group by an ID then get the highest "rank" for that ID with something like this:

```
df1.groupby(['Name'],as_index=False)['Placement'].agg(getHighestPlacement)
```

For example,

```
Name   Placement
Joe    First Place
Joe    Second Place
Joe    Second Place
Jill   Third Place    
Jill   Second Place
Jill   Second Place
```

I'd like to return

```
Name    Placement
Joe     First Place
Jill    Second Place
```

I'm thinking of writing a function to do it, maybe defining a list of the placements in order and then try to get the minimum index and pass that pack into the list to return the element at that index? I need the function to take in a Series and return one string. What would be the cleanest way to go about this? I'm still pretty new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Placement` column to [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-data), then sort and group it:

```
d = {'Name':['Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill'],
     'Placement': ['First Place', 'Second Place', 'Second Place', 'Third Place', 'Second Place', 'Second Place']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# convert Placement to Categorical
df['Placement'] = pd.Categorical(df['Placement'], categories=['First Place', 'Second Place', 'Third Place'], ordered=True)
print(df.loc[df.sort_values('Placement').groupby('Name')['Placement'].head(1).index])
```

Prints:

```
   Name     Placement
0   Joe   First Place
4  Jill  Second Place
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But is there a way to read that first category (.head(1).index) as part of an aggregation that could be used with .agg? The reason I was thinking of doing it in some function form was so that I could ultimately do something like .agg('Placement' : 'getHighestPlacement', 'end_date':'max') as I have another column I need to aggregate to get the max date.

Comment: @just4lizzy If I understand you right, you can sort by `df.sort_values(['Placement', 'end_date'], ascending=[True, False])` and then do the grouby - that way you will get max `end_date` also.

Comment: I think that would work if one row has the minimum placement and maximum end date, but the data can have that the minimum placement and maximum end date  on different rows under the same Name, so I don't sorting would work. I'd need to get them separately. That's why I was thinking of doing it in the aggregation step?

Comment: I figured it out! Your step to convert the column to Categorical and ordered worked so I could do a regular max/min aggregation on it.